# jquery stops working when using document ready statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my code has been working fine. However, as soon as I place an on document ready statement the entire script stops working. I have tried placing an alert within the document ready function and it passes properly.

I'm really uncertain what the problem is, and how I would go about debugging. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

`JS code`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sample").effect("transfer", {
        to: $("#{{ $stimuli['sample'][0] }}")
    }, 7000, function() {

      $('#{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}')
        .append('<a href="response/{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}"><div class="ui-effects-transfer"></div></a>');

      $('#{{$stimuli['sample'][0]}}').css("border", "10px solid green");
    });

});
```

Some console messages:

```
    'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.
firebug-lite.js:15683 'Performance.onwebkitresourcetimingbufferfull' is deprecated. Please use 'Performance.onresourcetimingbufferfull' instead.
http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/skin/xp/pixel_transparent.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/public/assets/css/media-queries.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**NEW UPDATE** Was missing a few errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/js/init.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/public/assets/css/media-queries.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/js/modernizr.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/js/jquery.flexslider.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
active:94 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function
firebug-lite.js:11883 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
chrome-extension://bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/firebug-lite.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)fetchResource @ firebug-lite.js:11884
firebug-lite.js:30396 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
firebug-lite.js:30396 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.
firebug-lite.js:15683 'Performance.onwebkitresourcetimingbufferfull' is deprecated. Please use 'Performance.onresourcetimingbufferfull' instead.
http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/skin/xp/pixel_transparent.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/pp/public/public/assets/css/media-queries.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: you get any errors?check console

Comment: are you including jQuery before this script or after? console may say something like $ undefined variable.

Comment: my jquery script is after my inclusion of the jquery files.

Check update on main post about console errors. However, none were shown in firebug

Comment: From your updated error: "active:94 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function"
Theres a problem right there you can debug.

Comment: But I have attached the jquery ui files. Why is it not a function? I've gotten it from the UI documentation... How would I go about fixing the issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point there to verify that $("#sample") exists?

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. It's because I'm using laravel, and I had to use {{ asset('source')}} command to get it working. Thanks for the direction you led me into.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your HTML is being dynamically created you should use the `.on` instead of the standard `.ready`, Im not sure if this will fix your problem as I'm not 100% what's going wrong as you've provided very minimal information.

Also make sure that your `<script src='jquery.js'></script>` is at the bottom of the `html` page. This ensures that the html loads first and then the javascript. Below is an example of the `.on('ready')`

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
   // Put your code in here
});
```

#### Edit:

Okay I think I may know your issue, make sure that your `JQUERY UI` script is being attached to the document `AFTER` your `JQUERY`. So for example it should look something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="YOUR_CUSTOM_SCRIPT_.JS"></script> <!-- Put your document.ready function here -->
```

Comment: Where is he supposed to use `.on()`? He's not binding any event handlers. And the location of the script doesn't matter if you use `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I tried that. And still it does not work. I have the jquery and jquery ui raw files attached at the top of the page. I thought I should have the jquery files at the top? If the jquery files are at the bottom, should I place them above the my jquery code?

Comment: @JPFoster It looks like the browser isn't registering the `.effect()` function and a lot of your resources are not being found!

Make sure that you've linked them correctly! Because you're getting 404's meaning the file isn't being found

Comment: I don't understand how... Since i have this at the top of the page. 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting, check my edit, maybe it will help. @JPFoster

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. It's because I'm using laravel, and I had to use {{ asset('source')}} command to get it working. Thanks for the direction you led me into.

Comment: No worries! Good luck with whatever your creating. @JPFoster +1 maybe ;)